# Visual Studio 2017 bin\roslyn files locked during build

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am running VS2017 version 26430.13 and every time I try to build a web project I get errors that access to the files in the bin\roslyn is denied. 
Over a period of about 5 minutes the files are unlocked and I can build but the 5 minute delay is unacceptable.

These are the files that stay locked:

- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll
- Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
- System.Collections.Immutable.dll
- System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll
- System.IO.Compression.dll
- System.IO.FileSystem.dll
- System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
- System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
- System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dl
- System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dl
- System.ValueTuple.dll
- VBCSCompiler.exe

Comment: What type of project?

Comment: As stated above a "web project".  Specifically an ASP.Net MVC project.

Comment: What version of ASP.Net? .Net Core? Is it running?

Comment: ASP.Net MVC 5.  I'm guessing it has something to do with an analyzer that is running in VS2017 someplace.

Comment: I've the same issue, I've logged it with MS here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71302/binroslyn-files-locked-during-build.html

Comment: Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: stopping or removing the Anti-Malware is against company policy.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

UPDATE the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package to V1.0.7

- Find Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform from NuGet
  Uninstall Old version
  Install V1.0.7 or latest

Comment: I'm still experiencing the same problem with v1.0.8. Why are the files locked?

Comment: upgrade from 1.0.7 to 2.0.1 solved the issue for me. (Still had it in v1.0.7)

Comment: Didn't solve the issue for me.  Still occurs with 2.0.1

Comment: I updated that to latest (3.6.0) and it was fixed.

Comment: I am facing this issue in v3.6.0. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 142):

Just open task manager and kill any instances of VBCSCompiler.exe. You don't even need to close Visual Studio.

Comment: Works! This saved me a lot of hassle. Thanks.

Comment: Run this from command line as administrator taskkill -im VBCSCompiler.exe -f

Comment: "Just" in this context, is a very dangerous word in computer programming.

Comment: P E R F E C T!!

Comment: you are my hero!

Comment: You are brilliant or what? Thanks!

Comment: What is this .exe

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is used for intellisense. In some versions of VS, it doesn't close properly and causes all sorts of false build and test issues. No harm closing it though, as it will spawn a new instance when needed.

Comment: This is the one!

Answer (score 14):

Instead of killing the process manually, you may use the following commands in a Pre-Build Event:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq VBCSCompiler.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "VBCSCompiler.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (taskkill /IM VBCSCompiler.exe /F) else (verify >NUL)
```

Answer (score 10):

A workaround is close VS, open task manager and kill any instances of VBCSCompiler.exe

(Thanks Tom John: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71302/binroslyn-files-locked-during-build.html)

Answer (score 10):

### Revert the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` package to `V1.0.4`

This advice came from a comment on the developer community problem report https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/79954/view.html.

We were on v1.0.5 and experienced locked files frequently.  After reverting the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package to V1.0.4 we are no longer experiencing locked files.

Comment: I have verified that upgrading to v1.0.7 also resolves the issue.

Comment: I had the problem the most with 1.0.4 so I don't think that's going to solve it for everyone. It does happen much less now, but I that was when I upgraded Visual Studio rather than upgrading to 1.07.

Answer (score 7):

**Project > Manage NuGet Packages... > Installed(tab)** > in search input set this:

```
codedom
```

click to update
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have VS 2017 Enterprise and for me the issue was resolved by this:

1. Downgraded Microsoft.Net.Compilers **from 2.3.1 to 2.3.0**
2. Downgraded Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform **from 1.0.5 to 1.0.4**.

Answer (score 1):

Install **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.BinFix** nuget
It fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

for me updating the nuget package...

> Microsoft.Net.Compilers

to the latest at the time of this post **2.7.0** fixed this for me. it was version **1.3.2**

Comment: I am facing this issue in v3.6.0. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

For me I just open solution in file explorer and delete bin folders of all projects in it. now it's working fine.

Comment: If I try to delete bin folders, I have an error that another process is using files.

Comment: @FrenkyB close visual studios and try to delete them

Answer (score 1):

In VS2017 & VS2019, this can happen when IIS Express is still running. Open the tray next to the clock, hover over the IIS Express icon running, right-click on the icon, click "Exit", confirm prompt, close active running worker processes. This can also be true when trying to publish your web project as well.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting this dll Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did these two steps:

1. uninstall-package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
2. Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -Version 1.0.8

Answer (score 0):

Before you try anything drastic, restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in MVC 5. I just opened Nuget Package Manager, searched and updated the following:

```
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

Comment: Could you expand up on your answer to include how you did what you're saying to do?

Comment: I am facing this issue in v3.6.0. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Nitesh : I had the same problem with version 3.11, the fix was to a) close VS, b) manually delete the `obj` and `bin` folders manually, c) restart VS and then d) rebuild. Not closing VS simply did not work as it would recreate the folders constantly.

Comment: @SolarBear it didnt work for me. I had to downgrade as other answers

Answer (score -2):

Update the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` package to `V1.0.6`